# Python : Solving a problem of finding a combination which satisfies a particular condition

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, combinations, mathematical-optimization

I am encountering a problem which I am unable to solve using normal brute force approach.
**Problem**-I am trying to find a combination of 50 years taken 30 at a time without repetition, such that their mean and coefficient of variation lies in particular range.
I am using `itertools combinations` for it.
But the issue is , no of total combinations are - `47129212243960` which are taking too long to calculate . 
Is there any way to do it more efficiently?
Dataset is of following format-

```
Yrs       Prs_90      Prs_80      Prs_70

2012  499.934588  521.512345  425.189729
2013  579.063531  477.782099  256.382494
2014  458.415624  456.480642  363.309507
```

I am calculating the mean and coefficient of variation of `Prs_90 , Prs_80, Prs_70` and then finding a combination according to a threshold which depends on mean and coefficient of variation.
Edit- Coefficient of Variation(CV) = Standard Deviation(x)/Mean(x)

The condition for the selection of the required combination to be selected is-

```
if (mean >= 501 and <= 570) and ((0.13<=CV<=0.17) or(0.23<=CV<=0.27) or(0.23 <=CV <=27)
```

or

```
if (mean >= 451 and <= 460) and ((0.13<=CV<=0.17) or(0.23<=CV<=0.27) 
or(0.33 <=CV <=37):
```

or

```
if (mean >= 391 and <= 400) and ((0.13<=CV<=0.17) or(0.23<=CV<=0.27) 
or(0.33 <=CV <=37)):
```

I need the combination corresponding to each of the above conditions.

**Edit-**
I am first reordering the dataframe provided above in the following format-

```
             Yrs      Prs_80      Prs_70
Prs_90                                  
579.063531  2013  477.782099  256.382494
477.758138  2044  475.458614  259.228592
492.957830  2036  408.590138  281.921215
541.632294  2042  430.990568  290.163454
565.369062  2024  420.107058  296.545395
409.979527  2027  379.740246  301.086631
347.702470  2052  610.775045  307.756455
460.657276  2016  301.774467  309.311562
```

and then I use following approach-

```
r =30
check1 = 1
check10 = 1
for p in combinations(test4.index,r):
  den = np.mean(p)
  num = np.std(p)
  cv = num/den
  if (den >= 561 and den <= 570 ) :
     if(cv>=0.13 or cv <= 0.17 and check1):
     check1=0
     print("Combination 1 done")

  elif(den>=391 and den <= 400):
     if(cv>=0.13 or cv < 0.17 and check10):
     check10 = 0
     print("Combination 10 done")
if(check1+check10==0)
break
```

I am here only taking for 2 conditions even then It is running for crores of iteration so complete processing of combinations will take more time.

I am using check1 and check10 as a signal as when I receive the following combination, I break the loop.

**Additional Information**-

```
           Prs_90      Prs_80      Prs_70
count   50.000000   50.000000   50.000000
mean   510.732700  445.366865  386.037076
std    113.773333   84.078209   80.987841
min    347.702470  233.335085  256.382494
25%    427.241363  390.745725  320.812298
50%    469.263029  439.407141  383.430153
75%    573.406731  512.019602  433.199140
max    854.819691  610.775045  644.588971
```

The CV of data is 25%.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What do you mean by "coefficient of variation" ? Can you give a formula for that ? How do you use your threshold (also give a formula please)?

Comment: Sorry , I added the details.

Comment: You could transform your CV inequalities to StdDev inequalities and then test the combinations for their StdDev..... after all CV and Mean are linked by an equation

Comment: The issue is not that I can't transform it , the issue is It is taking too much time and I don't know how to optimise it

Comment: Can you be a little more specific ? Such as : Your original dataset looks like a pandas Dataframe, am i right ? Can you provide a [mcve] that tells us how your problem should be solved ? Even though it is not Big Data, we'll take it into account.

Comment: Yes, my original dataset is pandas dataframe , I have pasted the dataset for only few years, in total it is 50 years data so 50 rows.

Comment: CV is not μ/σ but rather σ/μ. 

I am not sure what `a combination of 50 years taken 30 at a time without repetition` means, but I suspect this problem can be formulated as an MINLP problem (mixed-integer nonlinear programming). There are solvers for this type of models.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen Thanks , I updated it. `combination of 50 years taken 30 at a time without repetition` is 50C30, its a way of selecting combination .Here is a little bit of more information regarding combination-https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination

Comment: Ok... it is a combinaison of 30 elements among 50 :S

Comment: Yes you are correct but mathematically few people say like this.

Comment: If you have to find one and only one combination for each PRS, why not sorting the each PRS successively, including each element from the smallest to the biggest until the conditions are broken. Added an element always bigger will increase the Mean. You can add and remove elements according to the broken condition

Comment: Yes, I did sorted them but in the first case it ran for 138 crores combinations in 1 day which I think is a very crude way to do things so I stopped it and now again thinking again for another solution

Comment: `combination of 50 years taken 30 at a time without repetition` seems to mean `select 30 (different) years taken from 50`. (Well, that is not what it means, but it is how we should read it).

Comment: Yes , you are right , that's what it means

Comment: `(0.23<=CV<=0.27) or(0.23 <=CV <=27)` ??? Why not just `(0.23<=CV<=27)`

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen Apologies , it was a typo, I am struck on this problem since past few days so I am quite blanked out. Sorry

Comment: Do you have any a priori knowldege about the distribution of your data ?

Comment: @ma3oun You can check now

Answer (score 0):

I said something like this can be solved as an MINLP (Mixed Integer Nonlinear Programming) model. Let me give that a try.

I generated some random data as:

```
----     30 PARAMETER p  random data

year1  18.003,    year2  84.483,    year3  55.487,    year4  30.813,    year5  29.929,    year6  23.181
year7  35.633,    year8  85.771,    year9   7.644,    year10 50.521,    year11 99.814,    year12 58.295
year13 99.122,    year14 76.463,    year15 13.939,    year16 64.332,    year17 16.792,    year18 25.758
year19 67.224,    year20 44.100,    year21 36.610,    year22 35.793,    year23 14.018,    year24 15.860
year25 59.322,    year26 83.258,    year27 23.851,    year28 66.908,    year29 77.810,    year30 31.062
year31 11.939,    year32 50.736,    year33 16.857,    year34 87.374,    year35 27.246,    year36 29.296
year37 59.802,    year38 72.549,    year39 63.197,    year40 46.916,    year41 41.917,    year42 12.652
year43 32.107,    year44  5.609,    year45 34.516,    year46 19.028,    year47 64.927,    year48 56.514
year49 77.226,    year50 30.483


----     30 PARAMETER meanbounds  

               lo          up

mean1      10.000      20.000
mean2      30.000      40.000
mean3      50.000      60.000


----     30 PARAMETER cvbounds  

             lo          up

cv1       0.500       0.700
cv2       0.900       0.950


----     30 PARAMETER K                    =       30.000  number to select
```

The MINLP model:

[image]

Basically the model does three things:

1. select 30 points (via the `x(i)` variables)
2. select one interval for the mean (via `xm(k1)`)
3. select one interval for the CV (via `xcv(k2)`)

Some results:

```
----     74 VARIABLE x.L  select points

year1  1,    year2  1,    year3  1,    year4  1,    year5  1,    year6  1,    year7  1,    year9  1,    year10 1
year12 1,    year16 1,    year17 1,    year18 1,    year20 1,    year21 1,    year22 1,    year23 1,    year24 1
year27 1,    year30 1,    year32 1,    year33 1,    year35 1,    year37 1,    year40 1,    year42 1,    year43 1
year44 1,    year46 1,    year48 1


----     74 VARIABLE mu.L                  =       34.321  mean
            VARIABLE sigma.L               =       18.843  stdev
            VARIABLE cv.L                  =        0.549  coeff of variation

----     74 VARIABLE xm.L  select mean interval

mean2 1


----     74 VARIABLE xcv.L  select CV interval

cv1 1
```

I solved this with [Baron](https://www.minlp.com/baron). At least with this data set this approach seems to work. As there is no objective, this is basically a feasibility problem. A Constraint Programming solver may also work (although most have limited support for floating point variables).

Comment: Is there any other way  as I think, I need to purchase the software for this.

Comment: There are open source MINLP solvers such as [Couenne](https://projects.coin-or.org/Couenne) (it finds a different solution and takes a little bit longer on my data). Alternatively Baron can be accessed online via [NEOS](https://neos-server.org/neos/).